# Finding proper subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\omega$ denote the cube root of unity such that $\omega\neq 1$. I want to find the subfields properly contained in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$ and containing $\mathbb Q$ properly.

Two of then certainly $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb Q(\omega)$. I have been told that the correct answer is 4. But what are the other two subfields? Are they $\mathbb Q(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb Q(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$? I have no idea. Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Are you using Galois theory to do this problem?

Comment: No, I am not using Galois theory

Answer (score 1):

1. $\mathbb Q(\omega + \sqrt[3]2)$ is actually equal to $\mathbb Q(\omega,\sqrt[3]2)$. (I can't say this with 100% certainty since I didn't work it out by hand, but it should be.)
2. $\mathbb Q(\omega\sqrt[3]2)$ *is* a third subfield.
3. $\mathbb Q(\omega^2\sqrt[3]2)$ is the fourth subfield.

You're probably wondering where $\mathbb Q(\omega^2\sqrt[3]2)$ comes from. This field, along with $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ and $\mathbb(\omega\sqrt[3]2)$, is generated by a root of the polynomial $x^3-2$, for which $\mathbb Q(\omega,\sqrt[3]2)$ is a splitting field. In field theory, a good strategy is to take some special element $\alpha$ and look at the other roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the base field, called the [conjugates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_element_(field_theory)) of $\alpha$.

By the way, what I just said isn't a proof that these are the *only* nontrivial subfields, or that these subfields are *distinct*. You should be able to prove distinctness without too much trouble, but I'm not sure how to prove that we didn't miss any other subfields without using tools from Galois theory.

Comment: Rest sure number 1  is right.

Comment: Did you work it out by hand, or do you have some quick way to see that it's true? I would be really shocked if it were false, but I can't prove it at a glance

Comment: In general, a primitive element is of the form $\alpha + \lambda \beta$, where, $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of their respective irreducible polynomials  over $K$. And you take $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $$\lambda \notin \left\{\lambda_{ij} = \frac{\alpha_i - \alpha}{\beta - \beta_j} \in \mathbb C  \right\}$$ where $\alpha = \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m$ and $\beta = \beta_1 , \ldots , \beta_n$ are distinct roots of their respective irreducible polynomials.

Comment: Taking $\lambda =1$ garantees $\lambda$ is not in that finite set. There are some more details, but essentially this is it.

Comment: That's a nice criterion. But why is it true? (Does it hold over any field?)

Comment: Not any field. This is not true for finite fields in general. It holds for any finite extension $L \supset K \supset \mathbb Q$. There always exists $u \in L$ such that $L = K [u]$. $K$ is a field. The proof to this is constructive, meaning it gives you a way to find $u$, and is exactly the one I've showed you.

Comment: Notice here that $K \supset \mathbb Q$ tells us $K$ has characteristc $0$.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to think about that. I assume that if you carefully work through the (right) proof of the primitive element theorem, this criterion just falls out.

Comment: That's the idea.